# How to speed up the python requests in Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping this website https://www.saksfifthavenue.com/c/women-s-apparel. There are various product variants for each product like variations of sizes and colors as well as availability per variant but not all in one place I have to send an additional request to the custom url which includes `prod_id`, `color` and `size` this is the part where I am loosing the speed of scrapy because those additional requests are making scraping pretty slow and

I'd like to have a work around because I have a requirement to finish the scraper in under 6 hours so right now it's been over 5 hours and only 3k products has been scraped in total due to those variant requests processing one by one. And I'd like to speed things up for example processing those additional requests faster. Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import requests
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import re
import json
import html


class SaksFifthAvenueSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "safa-feeds"

    # custom settings
    custom_settings = {
        "LOG_FILE": "saks_fifth_avenue.log",
        "ITEM_PIPELINES": {
            "sdt.pipelines.SdtWasabiS3Pipeline": 300,
        },
    }

    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
        "Sec-GPC": "1",
    }

    params = {
        "cgid": "",
        "start": "0",
        "sz": "24",
        "hideLess": "true",
    }

    base_url = "https://www.saksfifthavenue.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-SaksFifthAvenue-Site/en_US/Search-UpdateGrid?"

    def start_requests(self):
        cgid_list = [
            "2534374306418048",
            "2534374306624247",
            "2534374306622828",
            "1608313652004",
            "2534374306418050",
            "2534374306418162",
            "2534374306418054",
            "1654108780232",
            "2534374306418205",
            "2534374306418206",
            "2534374306418217",
            "2534374306418192",
            "1608313652004",
            "2534374306418053",
        ]
        for cgid in cgid_list:
            self.params["cgid"] = cgid
            category_url = self.base_url + urlencode(self.params)
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=category_url, headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse_page_items
            )

    def parse_page_items(self, response):
        item_links = set(
            [
                "https://www.saksfifthavenue.com" + u.split("?")[0]
                for u in response.css("a.thumb-link.mw-100::attr(href)").extract()
            ]
        )
        inner_load = response.css("div.show-more ::attr(data-url)").get()
        if inner_load:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=inner_load, headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse_page_items
            )
        # next_page_no = response.css('a[aria-label="Next"]::attr(href)').get()
        # if next_page_no:
        #     self.params["start"] = next_page_no.split("&")[0].split("=")[-1]
        #     next_url = self.base_url + urlencode(self.params)
        #     yield scrapy.Request(
        #         url=next_url, headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse_page_items
        #     )

        for link in item_links:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=link, headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse_product_details
            )

    def parse_product_details(self, response):
        item = {}
        json_text = (
            response.css('script[type="application/ld+json"]')
            .get()
            .replace('<script type="application/ld+json">', "")
            .replace("</script>", "")
        )
        json_blob = json.loads(json_text)
        prod_id = response.css("div.container.product-detail::attr(data-pid)").get()
        colors = response.css("button::attr(data-adobelaunchproductcolor)").extract()
        sizes = response.css("li::attr(data-attr-value)").extract()
        item["product_id"] = prod_id
        item["product_brand"] = response.css("a.product-brand::text").get()
        item["product_name"] = response.css("h1.product-name::text").get()
        json_breadcrumbs_text = (
            response.css('script[type="application/ld+json"]')
            .extract()[-1]
            .replace('<script type="application/ld+json">', "")
            .replace("</script>", "")
        )
        bc_json_blob = json.loads(json_breadcrumbs_text)
        item["categories"] = [
            {f"category_{idx}": cat["name"]}
            for idx, cat in enumerate(bc_json_blob["itemListElement"], 1)
        ]
        item["slug"] = json_blob["offers"]["url"].split(".com")[-1]
        desc = json_blob["description"]
        item["description"] = re.sub("<[^<]+?>", " ", html.unescape(desc))
        item["product_variants"] = []
        item["color"] = response.css(
            "span.text2.color-value.attribute-displayValue::text"
        ).get()
        item["sizes"] = []
        for color in colors:
            for i_size in sizes:
                variant_url = (
                    response.url
                    + "?dwvar_"
                    + prod_id
                    + "_color="
                    + color.upper()
                    + "&dwvar_"
                    + prod_id
                    + f"_size={i_size}&pid="
                    + prod_id
                )
                resp = requests.get(variant_url, headers=self.headers)
                product_variants = Selector(text=resp.text)
                size = "".join(
                    list(
                        filter(
                            None,
                            [
                                s.replace("\n", "")
                                for s in product_variants.css("li")
                                .css("[selected] ::text")
                                .extract()
                            ],
                        )
                    )
                )
                disabled = (
                    product_variants.css("li")
                    .css("[disabled]")
                    .css("[selected] ::text")
                    .getall()
                )
                final_price = ""
                final_price = product_variants.css(
                    "span.formatted_sale_price.formatted_price.js-final-sale-price.bfx-price.bfx-list-price::text"
                ).get()
                if final_price is None:
                    final_price = product_variants.css(
                        "span.formatted_sale_price.formatted_price.js-final-sale-price.bfx-price.bfx-sale-price::text"
                    ).get()
                try:
                    old_price = product_variants.css(
                        "span.formatted_price.bfx-price.bfx-list-price ::text"
                    ).get()
                except:
                    old_price = ""

                if not disabled:
                    item["product_variants"].append(
                        {
                            "color": product_variants.css(
                                "span.text2.color-value.attribute-displayValue::text"
                            ).get(),
                            "size": size,
                            "status": "AVAILABLE",
                            "final_price": final_price,
                            "old_price": old_price,
                        }
                    )
                else:
                    item["product_variants"].append(
                        {
                            "color": product_variants.css(
                                "span.text2.color-value.attribute-displayValue::text"
                            ).get(),
                            "size": size,
                            "status": "NOT_AVAILABLE",
                            "final_price": final_price,
                            "old_price": old_price,
                        }
                    )

        if item["product_variants"] == []:
            size_selector = response.css(
                "ul.radio-group-list.size-attribute.swatch-display-three.show-size-dropdown"
            )
            for s in size_selector.css("li"):
                all_size_var = s.css("::text").getall()
                if not s.css("[disabled]"):
                    available = all_size_var
                    clean = list(filter(None, [c.replace("\n", "") for c in available]))
                    for out_si in clean:
                        item["sizes"].append({"size": out_si, "status": "AVAILABLE"})
                else:
                    out_of_stock = all_size_var
                    clean = list(
                        filter(None, [c.replace("\n", "") for c in out_of_stock])
                    )
                    for in_si in clean:
                        item["sizes"].append({"size": in_si, "status": "NOT_AVAILABLE"})

        if item["product_variants"] == [] and item["sizes"] == []:
            if response.css("div.form-group.show-size-dropdown-holder"):
                size_dropdown = response.css(
                    "ul.radio-group-list.size-attribute.swatch-display-three ::text"
                ).extract()
                clean_sizes = list(
                    filter(None, [s.replace("\n", "") for s in size_dropdown])
                )

                for dd_si in clean_sizes:
                    variant_url = (
                        response.url
                        + "?dwvar_"
                        + prod_id
                        + "_color="
                        + item["color"].upper()
                        + "&dwvar_"
                        + prod_id
                        + f"_size={dd_si}&pid="
                        + prod_id
                    )
                    resp = requests.get(variant_url, headers=self.headers)
                    product_variants = Selector(text=resp.text)
                    size = "".join(
                        list(
                            filter(
                                None,
                                [
                                    s.replace("\n", "")
                                    for s in product_variants.css("li")
                                    .css("[selected] ::text")
                                    .extract()
                                ],
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    disabled = (
                        product_variants.css("li")
                        .css("[disabled]")
                        .css("[selected] ::text")
                        .getall()
                    )
                    final_price = ""
                    final_price = product_variants.css(
                        "span.formatted_sale_price.formatted_price.js-final-sale-price.bfx-price.bfx-list-price::text"
                    ).get()
                    if final_price is None:
                        final_price = product_variants.css(
                            "span.formatted_sale_price.formatted_price.js-final-sale-price.bfx-price.bfx-sale-price::text"
                        ).get()
                    try:
                        old_price = product_variants.css(
                            "span.formatted_price.bfx-price.bfx-list-price ::text"
                        ).get()
                    except:
                        old_price = ""

                    if not disabled:
                        item["product_variants"].append(
                            {
                                "color": item["color"],
                                "size": size,
                                "status": "AVAILABLE",
                                "final_price": final_price,
                                "old_price": old_price,
                            }
                        )
                    else:
                        item["product_variants"].append(
                            {
                                "color": item["color"],
                                "size": size,
                                "status": "NOT_AVAILABLE",
                                "final_price": final_price,
                                "old_price": old_price,
                            }
                        )

        item["gender"] = ""
        bc_li = [b["name"] for b in bc_json_blob["itemListElement"]]

        if "Women's Clothing" in bc_li:
            item["gender"] = "Female"
        elif "Men" in bc_li or "Men's" in bc_li:
            item["gender"] = "Male"
        else:
            item["gender"] = "Female"
        if (
            "Kids" in bc_li
            and any("Boys" in s for s in bc_li)
            or any("Baby Boy" in s for s in bc_li)
        ):
            item["gender"] = "Boy"
        elif (
            "Kids" in bc_li
            and any("Girls" in s for s in bc_li)
            or any("Baby Girl" in s for s in bc_li)
        ):
            item["gender"] = "Girl"

        elif (
            any("Kids" in s for s in bc_li)
            and not any("Baby Girl" in s for s in bc_li)
            and not any("Baby Boy" in s for s in bc_li)
            and not any("Boys" in s for s in bc_li)
            and not any("Girls" in s for s in bc_li)
        ):
            item["gender"] = "Kids"

        elif any("Accessories" in s for s in bc_li):
            item["gender"] = ""

        else:
            item["gender"] = ""

        price_json_text = (
            response.css('script[type="text/javascript"]')
            .extract()[2]
            .replace('<script type="text/javascript">\npageDataObj = ', "")
            .replace(";\n</script>", "")
        )
        price_json_blob = json.loads(price_json_text)
        item["tag"] = price_json_blob["products"][0]["tags"]["feature_type"]
        item["price"] = [
            {
                "original_price": p["original_price"],
                "price": p["price"],
                "currency": json_blob["offers"]["priceCurrency"],
            }
            for p in price_json_blob["products"]
        ]
        item["images"] = json_blob["image"]

        yield item
```

Please can anyone have any tips or suggestions to how to optimize the python requests in scrapy? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well your bottleneck is the fact that you are using the requests lib to query each of the variants.   You should yield those requests back to the scrapy engine...

Comment: Any example of yielding those requests back to the scrapy engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments one area where performance gains can be made would be to eliminate the use of the `requests` lib and instead feed all of the additional requests for each of the product variants back into the scrapy engine.

You can do this by collecting all of the variant `urls` into a list and passing the list as an argument to callback methods, that exclusively parse the variant information from the variant page, and then recalling with the next variant url until there are none left.

I ran multiple tests using this strategy on various sized subsets of your requests and it consistently retrieved the same number of items as your code but in under half the time.

The code:

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import re
import json
import html


class SaksFifthAvenueSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "safa-feeds"

    # custom settings
    custom_settings = {
        "LOG_FILE": "saks_fifth_avenue1.log",
        "ITEM_PIPELINES": {
            "sdt.pipelines.SdtWasabiS3Pipeline": 300,
        },
    }

    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
        "Sec-GPC": "1",
    }

    params = {
        "cgid": "",
        "start": "0",
        "sz": "24",
        "hideLess": "true",
    }

    base_url = "https://www.saksfifthavenue.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-SaksFifthAvenue-Site/en_US/Search-UpdateGrid?"

    def start_requests(self):
        cgid_list = [
            "2534374306418048",
            "2534374306624247",
            "2534374306622828",
            "1608313652004",
            "2534374306418050",
            "2534374306418162",
            "2534374306418054",
            "1654108780232",
            "2534374306418205",
            "2534374306418206",
            "2534374306418217",
            "2534374306418192",
            "1608313652004",
            "2534374306418053",
        ]
        for i, cgid in enumerate(cgid_list):
            self.params["cgid"] = cgid
            category_url = self.base_url + urlencode(self.params)
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=category_url, headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse_page_items
            )

    def parse_page_items(self, response):
        item_links = set(
            [
                "https://www.saksfifthavenue.com" + u.split("?")[0]
                for u in response.css("a.thumb-link.mw-100::attr(href)").extract()
            ]
        )
        inner_load = response.css("div.show-more ::attr(data-url)").get()
        if inner_load:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=inner_load, headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse_page_items
            )
        # next_page_no = response.css('a[aria-label="Next"]::attr(href)').get()
        # if next_page_no:
        #     self.params["start"] = next_page_no.split("&")[0].split("=")[-1]
        #     next_url = self.base_url + urlencode(self.params)
        #     yield scrapy.Request(
        #         url=next_url, headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse_page_items
        #     )

        for i, link in enumerate(item_links):
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=link, headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse_product_details
            )

    def parse_product_details(self, response):
        item = {}
        json_text = (
            response.css('script[type="application/ld+json"]')
            .get()
            .replace('<script type="application/ld+json">', "")
            .replace("</script>", "")
        )
        json_blob = json.loads(json_text)
        prod_id = response.css("div.container.product-detail::attr(data-pid)").get()
        colors = response.css("button::attr(data-adobelaunchproductcolor)").extract()
        sizes = response.css("li::attr(data-attr-value)").extract()
        item["product_id"] = prod_id
        item["product_brand"] = response.css("a.product-brand::text").get()
        item["product_name"] = response.css("h1.product-name::text").get()
        json_breadcrumbs_text = (
            response.css('script[type="application/ld+json"]')
            .extract()[-1]
            .replace('<script type="application/ld+json">', "")
            .replace("</script>", "")
        )
        bc_json_blob = json.loads(json_breadcrumbs_text)
        item["categories"] = [
            {f"category_{idx}": cat["name"]}
            for idx, cat in enumerate(bc_json_blob["itemListElement"], 1)
        ]
        item["slug"] = json_blob["offers"]["url"].split(".com")[-1]
        desc = json_blob["description"]
        item["description"] = re.sub("<[^<]+?>", " ", html.unescape(desc))
        item["product_variants"] = []
        item["color"] = response.css(
            "span.text2.color-value.attribute-displayValue::text"
        ).get()
        item["sizes"] = []
        item["gender"] = ""
        bc_li = [b["name"] for b in bc_json_blob["itemListElement"]]

        if "Women's Clothing" in bc_li:
            item["gender"] = "Female"
        elif "Men" in bc_li or "Men's" in bc_li:
            item["gender"] = "Male"
        else:
            item["gender"] = "Female"
        if (
            "Kids" in bc_li
            and any("Boys" in s for s in bc_li)
            or any("Baby Boy" in s for s in bc_li)
        ):
            item["gender"] = "Boy"
        elif (
            "Kids" in bc_li
            and any("Girls" in s for s in bc_li)
            or any("Baby Girl" in s for s in bc_li)
        ):
            item["gender"] = "Girl"

        elif (
            any("Kids" in s for s in bc_li)
            and not any("Baby Girl" in s for s in bc_li)
            and not any("Baby Boy" in s for s in bc_li)
            and not any("Boys" in s for s in bc_li)
            and not any("Girls" in s for s in bc_li)
        ):
            item["gender"] = "Kids"

        elif any("Accessories" in s for s in bc_li):
            item["gender"] = ""

        else:
            item["gender"] = ""

        price_json_text = (
            response.css('script[type="text/javascript"]')
            .extract()[2]
            .replace('<script type="text/javascript">\npageDataObj = ', "")
            .replace(";\n</script>", "")
        )
        price_json_blob = json.loads(price_json_text)
        item["tag"] = price_json_blob["products"][0]["tags"]["feature_type"]
        item["price"] = [
            {
                "original_price": p["original_price"],
                "price": p["price"],
                "currency": json_blob["offers"]["priceCurrency"],
            }
            for p in price_json_blob["products"]
        ]
        variant_urls = []
        for color in colors:
            for i_size in sizes:
                variant_url = (
                    response.url
                    + "?dwvar_"
                    + prod_id
                    + "_color="
                    + color.upper()
                    + "&dwvar_"
                    + prod_id
                    + f"_size={i_size}&pid="
                    + prod_id
                )
                variant_urls.append(variant_url)
        item["images"] = json_blob["image"]
        size_selector = response.css(
                "ul.radio-group-list.size-attribute.swatch-display-three.show-size-dropdown"
            )
        if size_selector:
            for s in size_selector.css("li"):
                all_size_var = s.css("::text").getall()
                if not s.css("[disabled]"):
                    available = all_size_var
                    clean = list(filter(None, [c.replace("\n", "") for c in available]))
                    for out_si in clean:
                        item["sizes"].append({"size": out_si, "status": "AVAILABLE"})
                else:
                    out_of_stock = all_size_var
                    clean = list(
                        filter(None, [c.replace("\n", "") for c in out_of_stock])
                    )
                    for in_si in clean:
                        item["sizes"].append({"size": in_si, "status": "NOT_AVAILABLE"})
        clean_sizes_urls = []
        if response.css("div.form-group.show-size-dropdown-holder"):
            size_dropdown = response.css(
                "ul.radio-group-list.size-attribute.swatch-display-three ::text"
            ).extract()
            clean_sizes = list(
                filter(None, [s.replace("\n", "") for s in size_dropdown])
            )
            for dd_si in clean_sizes:
                if item["color"]:
                    variant_url = (
                        response.url
                        + "?dwvar_"
                        + prod_id
                        + "_color="
                        + item["color"].upper()
                        + "&dwvar_"
                        + prod_id
                        + f"_size={dd_si}&pid="
                        + prod_id
                    )
                    clean_sizes_urls.append(variant_url)
        if variant_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(variant_urls[0], headers=self.headers, cb_kwargs={"item": item, "variant_urls": variant_urls[1:], "clean_sizes_urls": clean_sizes_urls}, callback=self.parse_product_variants)
        elif clean_sizes_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(clean_sizes_urls[0], headers=self.headers, cb_kwargs={"item": item, "clean_sizes_urls": clean_sizes_urls[1:]}, callback=self.parse_clean_sizes)
        else:
            yield item

    def parse_product_variants(
        self, response, item, variant_urls, clean_sizes_urls):
        size = "".join(
            list(
                filter(
                    None,
                    [
                        s.replace("\n", "")
                        for s in response.css("li")
                        .css("[selected] ::text")
                        .extract()
                    ],
                )
            )
        )
        disabled = (
            response.css("li")
            .css("[disabled]")
            .css("[selected] ::text")
            .getall()
        )
        final_price = ""
        final_price = response.css(
            "span.formatted_sale_price.formatted_price.js-final-sale-price.bfx-price.bfx-list-price::text"
        ).get()
        if final_price is None:
            final_price = response.css(
                "span.formatted_sale_price.formatted_price.js-final-sale-price.bfx-price.bfx-sale-price::text"
            ).get()
        try:
            old_price = response.css(
                "span.formatted_price.bfx-price.bfx-list-price ::text"
            ).get()
        except:
            old_price = ""

        if not disabled:
            item["product_variants"].append(
                {
                    "color": response.css(
                        "span.text2.color-value.attribute-displayValue::text"
                    ).get(),
                    "size": size,
                    "status": "AVAILABLE",
                    "final_price": final_price,
                    "old_price": old_price,
                }
            )
        else:
            item["product_variants"].append(
                {
                    "color": response.css(
                        "span.text2.color-value.attribute-displayValue::text"
                    ).get(),
                    "size": size,
                    "status": "NOT_AVAILABLE",
                    "final_price": final_price,
                    "old_price": old_price,
                }
            )
        if len(variant_urls) > 0:
            yield scrapy.Request(variant_urls[0], headers=self.headers, cb_kwargs={"item": item, "variant_urls": variant_urls[1:], "clean_sizes_urls": clean_sizes_urls}, callback=self.parse_product_variants)
        elif len(clean_sizes_urls) > 0:
            yield scrapy.Request(clean_sizes_urls[0], headers=self.headers, cb_kwargs={"item": item, "clean_sizes_urls": clean_sizes_urls[1:]}, callback=self.parse_clean_sizes)
        else:
            yield item


    def parse_clean_sizes(self, response, item, clean_sizes_urls):
        size = "".join(
            list(
                filter(
                    None,
                    [
                        s.replace("\n", "")
                        for s in response.css("li")
                        .css("[selected] ::text")
                        .extract()
                    ],
                )
            )
        )
        disabled = (
            response.css("li")
            .css("[disabled]")
            .css("[selected] ::text")
            .getall()
        )
        final_price = ""
        final_price = response.css(
            "span.formatted_sale_price.formatted_price.js-final-sale-price.bfx-price.bfx-list-price::text"
        ).get()
        if final_price is None:
            final_price = response.css(
                "span.formatted_sale_price.formatted_price.js-final-sale-price.bfx-price.bfx-sale-price::text"
            ).get()
        try:
            old_price = response.css(
                "span.formatted_price.bfx-price.bfx-list-price ::text"
            ).get()
        except:
            old_price = ""

        if not disabled:
            item["product_variants"].append(
                {
                    "color": item["color"],
                    "size": size,
                    "status": "AVAILABLE",
                    "final_price": final_price,
                    "old_price": old_price,
                }
            )
        else:
            item["product_variants"].append(
                {
                    "color": item["color"],
                    "size": size,
                    "status": "NOT_AVAILABLE",
                    "final_price": final_price,
                    "old_price": old_price,
                }
            )
        if len(clean_sizes_urls) > 0:
            yield scrapy.Request(clean_sizes_urls[0], headers=self.headers, cb_kwargs={"item": item, "clean_sizes_urls": clean_sizes_urls[1:]}, callback=self.parse_clean_sizes)
        else:
            yield item
```

Note: It has not been tested with your pipeline

Comment: Awesome! you made it more robust and simple to understand I was struggling with that and couldn't figure out that logic so I had to use the requests module to get it working and your solution is simply great can't thank you enough.

Comment: my pleasure... it was a good question.  Hopefully it's enough to get you in the 6hour window. @X-somtheing

Comment: Thanks. your solution looks promising.

Comment: I have a question regarding yielding `variant_urls` and `clean_sizes_urls` in `parse_product_details` method why not running the loop instead of indexing? is there any particular reason?

Comment: One more thing I have noticed that spider is getting closed early without scraping all the pages.

Comment: I have explained the the pagination problem in another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75061129/how-to-handle-ajax-and-normal-pagination-in-scrapy if you have some time can you please take a look at it? thank you

Comment: @X-somtheing  I am not sure what you mean by running the loop instead of indexing?  Not sure why the spider is closing early, but I will look into it

Comment: Actually I was referring to this line `if len(variant_urls) > 0:
            yield scrapy.Request(variant_urls[0], headers=self.headers, cb_kwargs={"item": item, "variant_urls": variant_urls[1:], "clean_sizes_urls": clean_sizes_urls}, callback=self.parse_product_variants)` with this `parse_product_variants` method always process the first url instead of processing each url and empty the list eventually so I was thinking  instead of `variant_urls[0]` wouldn't it be better to use `variant_urls.pop(0)`?

Comment: It would be the same.  So use whichever syntax you prefer.

Comment: Hi @Alexander! Hope you are doing great. I have a similar problem to that previous question of mine I tried to solve it with the solution you posted last time but it isn't working with the problem I have in hand. I have posted the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76218980/scrapy-chain-of-requests-to-combine-items-from-multiple-requests if you have some time can you please take a look at it? Thank you.