# How to handle Ajax and normal pagination in Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping this website https://www.saksfifthavenue.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-SaksFifthAvenue-Site/en_US/Search-UpdateGrid?cgid=2534374306418048&start=0&sz=24&hideLess=true it is api url I guess which uses ajax pagination and normal pagination as well. Website using ajax pagination to load the items partially once all the items loaded then page shows the conventional numbered list of page numbers. I have write the scraper and handling the pagination by simply checking if `show more` div is present in the page or not. Here is the html source for that div:

```
<div class="show-more invisible">
  <div class="text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary col-12 col-sm-4" data-url="https://www.saksfifthavenue.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-SaksFifthAvenue-Site/en_US/Search-UpdateGrid?cgid=2534374306418048&start=21&sz=24&hideLess=true">
More Results
</button>
</div>
</div>
```

If div is presented in the page I am fetching the `data-url` and parse items from that url. Once the show more div is no more spider will look for next page div which is look like this:

```
<p class="page-item d-flex  next">
<a class="d-inline-block" aria-label="Next" href="https://www.saksfifthavenue.com/c/women-s-apparel?start=37724&sz=24"></a>
</p>
```

This is little bit tricky to work with it since I am using api url and next page url is the normal website url so I am only extracting start value from it and update the params. Here is the spider:

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import re
import json
import html


class SaksFifthAvenueSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "safa-feeds"

    # custom settings
    custom_settings = {
        "LOG_FILE": "safa-feeds-spider.log",
        "ITEM_PIPELINES": {
            "sdt.pipelines.SdtWasabiS3Pipeline": 300,
        },
    }

    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
        "Sec-GPC": "1",
    }

    params = {
        "cgid": "",
        "start": "0",
        "sz": "24",
        "hideLess": "true",
    }

    base_url = "https://www.saksfifthavenue.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-SaksFifthAvenue-Site/en_US/Search-UpdateGrid?"

    def start_requests(self):
        cgid_list = [
            "2534374306418048",
            # "2534374306624247",
            # "2534374306622828",
            # "1608313652004",
            # "2534374306418050",
            # "2534374306418162",
            # "2534374306418054",
            # "1654108780232",
            # "2534374306418205",
            # "2534374306418206",
            # "2534374306418217",
            # "2534374306418192",
            # "1608313652004",
            # "2534374306418053",
        ]
        for i, cgid in enumerate(cgid_list):
            self.params["cgid"] = cgid
            category_url = self.base_url + urlencode(self.params)
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=category_url, headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse_page_items
            )

    def parse_page_items(self, response):
        item_links = set(
            [
                "https://www.saksfifthavenue.com" + u.split("?")[0]
                for u in response.css("a.thumb-link.mw-100::attr(href)").extract()
            ]
        )
        inner_load = response.css("div.show-more ::attr(data-url)").get()
        if inner_load:
            print(inner_load)
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=inner_load,
                headers=self.headers,
                callback=self.parse_page_items,
            )
        next_page_no = response.css('a[aria-label="Next"]::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page_no:
            self.params["start"] = next_page_no.split("&")[0].split("=")[-1]
            next_url = self.base_url + urlencode(self.params)
            print(next_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=next_url, headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse_page_items
            )

        for link in item_links:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=link, headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse_product_details
            )

    def parse_product_details(self, response):
        item = {}
        json_text = response.css('script[type="application/ld+json"]').get()
        if json_text is not None:
            clean_text = json_text.replace(
                '<script type="application/ld+json">', ""
            ).replace("</script>", "")
            json_blob = json.loads(clean_text)
            prod_id = response.css("div.container.product-detail::attr(data-pid)").get()
            colors = response.css(
                "button::attr(data-adobelaunchproductcolor)"
            ).extract()
            sizes = response.css("li::attr(data-attr-value)").extract()
            item["product_id"] = prod_id
            item["product_brand"] = response.css("a.product-brand::text").get()
            item["product_name"] = response.css("h1.product-name::text").get()
            json_breadcrumbs_text = (
                response.css('script[type="application/ld+json"]')
                .extract()[-1]
                .replace('<script type="application/ld+json">', "")
                .replace("</script>", "")
            )
            bc_json_blob = json.loads(json_breadcrumbs_text)
            if "itemListElement" in bc_json_blob:
                item["categories"] = [
                    {f"category_{idx}": cat["name"]}
                    for idx, cat in enumerate(bc_json_blob["itemListElement"], 1)
                ]
            else:
                item["categories"] = []
            item["slug"] = json_blob["offers"]["url"].split(".com")[-1]
            desc = json_blob["description"]
            item["description"] = re.sub("<[^<]+?>", " ", html.unescape(desc))
            item["product_variants"] = []
            item["color"] = response.css(
                "span.text2.color-value.attribute-displayValue::text"
            ).get()
            item["sizes"] = []
            item["gender"] = ""
            if "itemListElement" in bc_json_blob:
                bc_li = [b["name"] for b in bc_json_blob["itemListElement"]]

                if "Women's Clothing" or "Beauty" in bc_li:
                    item["gender"] = "Female"
                elif any("Men" in s for s in bc_li) or any("Men's" in s for s in bc_li):
                    item["gender"] = "Male"
                else:
                    item["gender"] = "Female"
                if (
                    "Kids" in bc_li
                    and any("Boys" in s for s in bc_li)
                    or any("Baby Boy" in s for s in bc_li)
                ):
                    item["gender"] = "Boy"
                elif (
                    "Kids" in bc_li
                    and any("Girls" in s for s in bc_li)
                    or any("Baby Girl" in s for s in bc_li)
                ):
                    item["gender"] = "Girl"

                elif (
                    any("Kids" in s for s in bc_li)
                    and not any("Baby Girl" in s for s in bc_li)
                    and not any("Baby Boy" in s for s in bc_li)
                    and not any("Boys" in s for s in bc_li)
                    and not any("Girls" in s for s in bc_li)
                ):
                    item["gender"] = "Kids"

                elif any("Accessories" in s for s in bc_li):
                    item["gender"] = ""

            price_json_text = (
                response.css('script[type="text/javascript"]')
                .extract()[2]
                .replace('<script type="text/javascript">\npageDataObj = ', "")
                .replace(";\n</script>", "")
            )
            price_json_blob = json.loads(price_json_text)
            item["tag"] = price_json_blob["products"][0]["tags"]["feature_type"]
            item["price"] = [
                {
                    "original_price": p["original_price"],
                    "price": p["price"],
                    "currency": json_blob["offers"]["priceCurrency"],
                }
                for p in price_json_blob["products"]
            ]
            variant_urls = []
            for color in colors:
                for i_size in sizes:
                    variant_url = (
                        response.url
                        + "?dwvar_"
                        + prod_id
                        + "_color="
                        + color.upper()
                        + "&dwvar_"
                        + prod_id
                        + f"_size={i_size}&pid="
                        + prod_id
                    )
                    variant_urls.append(variant_url)
            item["images"] = json_blob["image"]
            size_selector = response.css(
                "ul.radio-group-list.size-attribute.swatch-display-three.show-size-dropdown"
            )
            if size_selector:
                for s in size_selector.css("li"):
                    all_size_var = s.css("::text").getall()
                    if not s.css("[disabled]"):
                        available = all_size_var
                        clean = list(
                            filter(None, [c.replace("\n", "") for c in available])
                        )
                        for out_si in clean:
                            item["sizes"].append(
                                {"size": out_si, "status": "AVAILABLE"}
                            )
                    else:
                        out_of_stock = all_size_var
                        clean = list(
                            filter(None, [c.replace("\n", "") for c in out_of_stock])
                        )
                        for in_si in clean:
                            item["sizes"].append(
                                {"size": in_si, "status": "NOT_AVAILABLE"}
                            )
            clean_sizes_urls = []
            if response.css("div.form-group.show-size-dropdown-holder"):
                size_dropdown = response.css(
                    "ul.radio-group-list.size-attribute.swatch-display-three ::text"
                ).extract()
                clean_sizes = list(
                    filter(None, [s.replace("\n", "") for s in size_dropdown])
                )
                for dd_si in clean_sizes:
                    if item["color"]:
                        variant_url = (
                            response.url
                            + "?dwvar_"
                            + prod_id
                            + "_color="
                            + item["color"].upper()
                            + "&dwvar_"
                            + prod_id
                            + f"_size={dd_si}&pid="
                            + prod_id
                        )
                        clean_sizes_urls.append(variant_url)
            if variant_urls:
                yield scrapy.Request(
                    variant_urls[0],
                    headers=self.headers,
                    cb_kwargs={
                        "item": item,
                        "variant_urls": variant_urls[1:],
                        "clean_sizes_urls": clean_sizes_urls,
                    },
                    callback=self.parse_product_variants,
                )
            elif clean_sizes_urls:
                yield scrapy.Request(
                    clean_sizes_urls[0],
                    headers=self.headers,
                    cb_kwargs={"item": item, "clean_sizes_urls": clean_sizes_urls[1:]},
                    callback=self.parse_clean_sizes,
                )

            yield item

    def parse_product_variants(self, response, item, variant_urls, clean_sizes_urls):
        size = "".join(
            list(
                filter(
                    None,
                    [
                        s.replace("\n", "")
                        for s in response.css("li").css("[selected] ::text").extract()
                    ],
                )
            )
        )
        disabled = (
            response.css("li").css("[disabled]").css("[selected] ::text").getall()
        )
        final_price = ""
        final_price = response.css(
            "span.formatted_sale_price.formatted_price.js-final-sale-price.bfx-price.bfx-list-price::text"
        ).get()
        if final_price is None:
            final_price = response.css(
                "span.formatted_sale_price.formatted_price.js-final-sale-price.bfx-price.bfx-sale-price::text"
            ).get()
        try:
            old_price = response.css(
                "span.formatted_price.bfx-price.bfx-list-price ::text"
            ).get()
        except:
            old_price = ""

        if not disabled:
            item["product_variants"].append(
                {
                    "color": response.css(
                        "span.text2.color-value.attribute-displayValue::text"
                    ).get(),
                    "size": size,
                    "status": "AVAILABLE",
                    "final_price": final_price,
                    "old_price": old_price,
                }
            )
        else:
            item["product_variants"].append(
                {
                    "color": response.css(
                        "span.text2.color-value.attribute-displayValue::text"
                    ).get(),
                    "size": size,
                    "status": "NOT_AVAILABLE",
                    "final_price": final_price,
                    "old_price": old_price,
                }
            )
        if len(variant_urls) > 0:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                variant_urls[0],
                headers=self.headers,
                cb_kwargs={
                    "item": item,
                    "variant_urls": variant_urls[1:],
                    "clean_sizes_urls": clean_sizes_urls,
                },
                callback=self.parse_product_variants,
            )
        elif len(clean_sizes_urls) > 0:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                clean_sizes_urls[0],
                headers=self.headers,
                cb_kwargs={"item": item, "clean_sizes_urls": clean_sizes_urls[1:]},
                callback=self.parse_clean_sizes,
            )
        yield item

    def parse_clean_sizes(self, response, item, clean_sizes_urls):
        size = "".join(
            list(
                filter(
                    None,
                    [
                        s.replace("\n", "")
                        for s in response.css("li").css("[selected] ::text").extract()
                    ],
                )
            )
        )
        disabled = (
            response.css("li").css("[disabled]").css("[selected] ::text").getall()
        )
        final_price = ""
        final_price = response.css(
            "span.formatted_sale_price.formatted_price.js-final-sale-price.bfx-price.bfx-list-price::text"
        ).get()
        if final_price is None:
            final_price = response.css(
                "span.formatted_sale_price.formatted_price.js-final-sale-price.bfx-price.bfx-sale-price::text"
            ).get()
        try:
            old_price = response.css(
                "span.formatted_price.bfx-price.bfx-list-price ::text"
            ).get()
        except:
            old_price = ""

        if not disabled:
            item["product_variants"].append(
                {
                    "color": item["color"],
                    "size": size,
                    "status": "AVAILABLE",
                    "final_price": final_price,
                    "old_price": old_price,
                }
            )
        else:
            item["product_variants"].append(
                {
                    "color": item["color"],
                    "size": size,
                    "status": "NOT_AVAILABLE",
                    "final_price": final_price,
                    "old_price": old_price,
                }
            )
        if len(clean_sizes_urls) > 0:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                clean_sizes_urls[0],
                headers=self.headers,
                cb_kwargs={"item": item, "clean_sizes_urls": clean_sizes_urls[1:]},
                callback=self.parse_clean_sizes,
            )

        yield item
```

Here is the page with list of numbers pagination: https://www.saksfifthavenue.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-SaksFifthAvenue-Site/en_US/Search-UpdateGrid?cgid=2534374306418048&start=37698&sz=24&hideLess=true

My problem is, there is around 38,723 items as of now but I am getting only 2k or 3k items I tried to debug by looking into the selectors checking if spider reaching to the `next_page_no` and `inner_load` and processing it is working fine but still not fetching all the pages spider quits early way before scraping all the pages. I couldn't find the issue. Can anyone please help me out here? Thank you!

Comment: It's possible that you are being booted or ratelimited by the website.  That is what happened to me.  Do your logs show a bunch of `403` errors at the end of the crawl?

Comment: Few of them showing `403` but they are getting retried and getting `200` after that because I have enabled the retry in the `settings.py` .

Comment: I am getting `Redirecting (302)` a lot though. `Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.saksfifthave.kr/?utm_source=REQUEST-URI&utm_medium=redirect> from <GET https://www.saksfifthavenue.com/product/samira-13-14k-yellow-gold--amp--multi-gemstone-y-necklace-0400017645253.html>`

Comment: I am still not permitted to access the website.  Doesn't look like I will be able to help until they let me back on

Comment: Ohh! can you try this url https://www.saksfifthavenue.com/c/women-s-apparel and check the network tab when scroll it will generate the fresh api url?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251038/newroom   join chatroom @X-Something

Comment: they finally let me back on the site.  Did you figure this out already?

Comment: Just a temporary patch I guess as in instead of using next page I am generating the paginated urls and making requests. Here is the patched one https://pastebin.com/YckYpqxM I appreciate if you take a look at it and let me know if this approach is good enough or not.

Comment: using the paginated urls approach scraper became pretty slow for example scraping 85k+ pages in 13 o 14 hours with concurrent requests set to 32 which is too long and couldn't figured that out how to speed that up.

Comment: It looks fine to me.  Moving any faster than that could get you booted for several days too so it could be a good thing

Comment: Hmm... valid point. Thanks for the helpful guidance really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you think if I use `scrapy-redis` by running the spider on multiple instances it would reduce the time?

Comment: I am not sure. I have never tried that.  It sounds like it would though.